# Can I assume that all execution of a method will be on the same thread in C#?

Tags: c#

Consider the following method

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    Thread initialThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    //Do something 
    Thread endingThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    Debug.Assert(object.ReferenceEquals(initialThread, endingThread));
}
```

Will the assertion always pass in C#, assuming the code is compiled and is not an iterator?

Comment: I'd say the thread won't change. However, there is no guarantee that the physical or logical CPU running this code will remain the same (Context switching)

Comment: My interest is in whether ThreadLocal or ThreadStatic will return the same object at the start and the end of the method, and that furthermore the thread won't be used in another method halfway through excecution (though that is not part of the question).

Comment: I've tried to include some ideas of where things can be different t your expectations in my answer. But, in this case, even given your explanations provided so far, it would be good to know to what end you need this knowledge - is it a security issue, or merely a performance one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in all current implementations, yes, but I don't think it's guaranteed. The documentation for `CurrentThread` says:

> **A** `Thread` that is the representation of the currently running thread.

**My emphasis**

(I was going to mention async also, but given we accept that the method is declared as `void`, I decided to rule that out)

---

From your comment:

> the thread won't be used in another method halfway through excecution

I don't think that *that* is guaranteed. Certainly, if you've any obvious code that `Wait()`s on a task or tasks, the current thread *may* be used to service some of those `Task`s.

There may be less obvious ways in which the thread could be used also.

---

One further item to be aware of is the existence of exception filters (not implementable in C#, but oddly available in VB) - where code higher up in the call stack can cause some (arbitrary) code to execute between an exception being thrown and your `catch` or `finally` handlers executing, if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

If you add "and not an async method" then I think that's a reasonable assumption, yes.

Basically iterator blocks and async methods fundamentally change the execution flow - everything else is "execute from top to bottom, on one thread". Of course your method could contain anonymous functions which are executed elsewhere, but I assume you're not including that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are NOT in an web environment, then that would be true aside from you doing some very interesting stuff in between.

If however you are in a web environment, then the IIS infrastructure could swap execution to another thread if the operation is taking a while, in which case that assumption would on occasion be false.

If you are dealing with a web environment, then instead of using ThreadStatic, I'd suggest storing in HttpContext.Current.Items - if it's not a web environment, then ThreadStatic is fine